# C++ function overloading by value type and constness (full details)

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

In C++, a function `f` taking a single argument of type `T` could have five different signatures (ignoring `volatile`):

```
void f(      T);   // #0
void f(      T&);  // #1
void f(const T&);  // #2
void f(      T&&); // #3
void f(const T&&); // #4
```

Assume that a **subset** of the above 5 methods is implemented in a program. What are the full rules that the compiler follows for selecting among the implemented overloads?

I would like to be able to discern in particular the cases in which:

- `f` is called on a variable declared as either `T`, `const T`, `T&`, `const T&`, `T&&`, `const T&&`;
- `f` is called on the output of a function declared as returning either  `T`, `const T`, `T&`, `const T&`, `T&&`, `const T&&`.

PS: I already found [here](https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/07/24/const-rvalue-references) a reasonably complete description of what happens without case #0, but I would like to learn what happens when you throw it into the mix.

PS2: The reason behind this question is that I often find myself doing tests to figure out how this kind of overload resolution works in some specific case. Although you can always solve each specific case by testing, it would be nice to know the general rule once and for all.

SUMMARY OF EDITS: explicitly ignored `volatile`, and clarifying that only a subset of #0-5 could be implemented.

Comment: For rvalue references you can take a look at this [nice article](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) by Thomas Becker.

Comment: Seems like it would be fairly easy to run a few tests and see which one of these gets called. Is there any particular reason you are unable to do so yourself?

Comment: `T t; f(t)` will show you that the first three are obviously ambiguous...

Comment: You can add to the mix `volatile` as it is also a part of the signature

Comment: `void f(const T&&);` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the number of tests needed is 2^5 * 12 = 384 (possible subsets of overloads times possible calls), so it is not that trivial. I might still manage to test all of them in the future, in which case I will self-answer my question

Comment: @PaulSanders `const T&&` is a valid type, although not very much useful in pratice

Comment: If you believe 384 tests is a challenge, you will find a typical business application, with tens of thousands of individual unit tests, to be quite a challenge.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if you believe it is not a challenge, maybe you can easily run them and answer the question! And besides doing the tests, you will also need to make sense of the results and infer a human-readable set of rules.

Comment: 0 and 1 are a single case. "Top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped from the parameter type" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: Oh, I don't need to prove to myself that it's possible to: a) use template meta-programming to generate a series of classes that has each possible combination of overloads, b) use SFINAE to determine whether each one of the 12 calls succeeds in overload resolution, c) Format the results. A few years ago I saw someone here solve Sieve of Erathothenes with template metaprogramming; it's surprising what a C++ compiler can do. P.S. Since I see six overloads, it looks to me like there are a total of `2^6-1` possible combination (or `2^6` including the case where none of the overloads are present).

Comment: @Caleth thanks, I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. `const T&&` makes no sense and

```
struct T{};

void f(T) {}
void f(const T&) {}

int main() {
    T t;
    f(t);
}
```

causes `error: call to 'f' is ambiguous`

Comment: `const T&&` is a valid type, although not very useful. I know that #0 clashes with others, and knowing how/when they clash is part of what I would like to know

Comment: @GiorgioAudrito The compiler can't know which function should be called. `t` is a valid argument for both functions.

Comment: @ThomasSablik not only is it valid, but neither signarute being a *better match* than the other plays an important role here.

Comment: @ThomasSablik this answers to the situation with subset of overloads {T, const T&} and call with variable T. However there are 2^5 * 12 - 1 = 383 other possible subsets of overloads and calls to discriminate; hence a general rule of how it works would be nice

Comment: @GiorgioAudrito the general rule of thumb is to not provide every possible overload just for the sake of providing it and, when dealing with such cases, it may be a good idea to consider *perfect forwarding* rather than creating a bunch of overloads.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I know that rule of thumb and perfect forwarding as well (which btw doesn't work when instead of `T` you have e.g. `std::pair<T,T>` as parameter type). However, the purpose of my question never was to try to provide the maximum number of overload possible (see the new PS2), just to know the overload resolution rules to in order to be able to understand what happens in any situation once and for all.

Comment: @GiorgioAudrito The compiler looks for a function that can be used without conversion. If it finds one, it takes it. If it finds multiple, it stops with an error. If it finds none, it looks for a function that can be used with one conversion. It's described here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: @ThomasSablik ok, but I don't see how this replies to my question (although maybe it might if you expand it). Besides, there is also a preference order among possible conversions to take into account.